# How to display ChoiceField in a template?

Tags: django, templates

Excerpts from
forms.py:

```
class ContForm():
    KafChoices = [(kaf.id, kaf.name) for kaf in Kaf.objects.all()]
    kaf = forms.ChoiceField(choices = KafChoices, required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cont
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('db3/index.html',
        {'form': ContForm()},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html:

```
{{ form.kaf }}
```

I get following output:
django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x01A110D0
instead of usual field. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ContForm` isn't inheriting from `forms.Form`?

Edit: looks like a modelform, in which case `ContForm(forms.ModelForm)`, but either way if you don't inherit from the form classes all `form.kaf` is doing is pulling up this python object that doesn't know what to do with itself.